# Llamar función de Python desde C++ | Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación

Tags: python, c++

Estoy queriendo llamar a una función de Python desde C++ pero me salta un error en la línea de la función PyDict_GetItemString. Recién estoy arrancando con la librería Python.h y no tengo idea de que puede llegar a ser. Alguna idea? Leí en algunas partes que capaz no estaba encontrando el modulo, pero de ser así no se como comprobarlo. El archivo python está en el mismo directorio que mi proyecto

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019 Versión 16.3.1 en Windows 7

C++

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyBytes_FromString("."));

    PyObject* modulo_nombre = PyUnicode_FromString("ModuloPrincipal");
    PyObject* modulo = PyImport_Import(modulo_nombre);
    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(modulo);

    PyObject* func = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "numero"); // Error
    PyObject* resultado = PyObject_CallObject(func, NULL);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Python

```
def numero()
    return 6
```

Error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que la línea que agrega la ruta al path de python debía utilizar el formato Unicode y no binario. En la mayoría de foros que leí utilizan la función PyString_FromString lo cual no funciona para Python 3 (que es el que estoy usando, me olvide de especificarlo), así que se debe utilizar PyUnicode_FromString para manejar las cadenas.

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString(".")); // Reemplazar PyBytes_FromString por PyUnicode_FromString

    PyObject* modulo_nombre = PyUnicode_FromString("ModuloPrincipal");
    PyObject* modulo = PyImport_Import(modulo_nombre);
    PyObject* dict = PyModule_GetDict(modulo);

    PyObject* func = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "numero");
    PyObject* resultado = PyObject_CallObject(func, NULL);
    int res = PyLong_AsLong(resultado);
    cout << "res: " << res << endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

PD: el siguiente código me ayudó a encontrar el error

```
if (PyErr_Occurred())
{
    cout << "Error";
    PyErr_Print();
}
else
{
    cout << "Sin errores";
}
```

Comprobando línea por línea, empezaron las fallas en la línea de importación

```
PyObject* modulo = PyImport_Import(modulo_nombre);
if (PyErr_Occurred())
{
    cout << "Error";
    PyErr_Print();
}
else
{
    cout << "Sin errores";
}
```

Al imprimir la falla se especificaba ahí el error de tipo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]